# Upgrade apache http client 3.1 to 4.3.5

Tags: java

what is the alternative of `PostMethod.setStrictMode(false)` in **httpclient version 4**. 
that is already deprecated in *3.1* and suggested to use below

```
 DefaultHttpParams.setParameter(String, Object);
```

But I am not sure what should be the *arg* which set strictly the method follows the HTTP protocol specification

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `RequestConfig` when setting up, like this:

```
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);

HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();     
builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
HttpClient client = builder.build();
```

The exact settings depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: HttpClient is already instantiated in that case how do I set ?

Comment: What do you want to set?